# K and &K using sense

Tags: c++, lambda

world!
As I have to know the sense of existence of the each symbol in C++, I would like to get acquainted with the reason why in the first variant of my code we use &K (on the last line), and in the second variant - just K (also in the last line).
Hope you understood the question.

1-st

`````````````````````````````
ifstream in("name.txt");

istream_iterator<int> it(in);
istream_iterator<int> eof;

ostream_iterator<int> out(cout, " ");

size_t K = 1;

remove_copy_if(it, eof, out, [&K](int a) {return K++ % 2 == 0; });





2-nd
````````````````````````````
size_t K;
cin >> K;

ifstream in ("name1.txt");

istream_iterator<string> it(in);
istream_iterator<string> eof;

ofstream out ("name2.txt");

ostream_iterator<string> fout(out, "\n");

remove_copy_if(it, eof, fout, [K](string e) {return e.length() > K; });
`````````````````````````````

Comment: Explore lambdas and capture lists.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture

Answer (score 0):

> why in the first variant of my code we use &K (on the last line), and in the second variant - just K (also in the last line)

Because the first lambda *modifies* `K` in `K++` - each lambda execution increments `K` value. So `K` has to be captured with `&K`.

The second lambda only uses `K` value, but does not modify it. So capturing just `K` by value is enough.